# Filling out nested form if user returns to original form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form for `customer` which is part of a series of order steps - enter customer information, enter delivery information etc etc. It automatically creates the customer when the user passes to the next stage, but if they then return to that step, they're forced to fill in the customer details again as the controller uses `@order.build_customer`.

What's the cleanest way to pre-fill the nested customer fields when returning to that page? Should I pass the customer ID as a parameter when a user hits 'edit'? Or try to `find_or_create`?

Code examples welcome - I'm still learning... Thanks!

Step in OrdersController

```
  def step_two
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @order.build_customer
  end
```

Nested form code in step_two.html.haml

```
  = form_for @order, :url => user_order_step_two_path(@user, @order), do |f|

    =f.fields_for :customer do |builder|
      =builder.label :name, "Contact name:"
      =builder.text_field :name
      =builder.label :email, "Email:"
      =builder.text_field :email

    = f.label :recipient_name, "Recipients name:"
    = f.text_field :recipient_name
    = f.label :recipient_address_1, "Address:"
    = f.text_field :recipient_address_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone, I ended up doing the following to pull customer data if an order existed, or create a new customer if they didn't. Needed to go in both edit and update parts of the controller.

```
if @order.customer_id?
  @customer = Customer.find(@order.customer_id)
else
  @order.build_customer
end
```

Then the nested form is prefilled if the customer is already associated with the order.